# add download& share button in text on image php

Tags: button, download, share

How can I add download & share button in text over image . php
download as a jpg format fix width or height, not a use a capture code or html2canvas only use php code
I hope you are solve my problems as soon as possible
Thank you very much
Have a nice day ahead

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far, and if there are any errors. Then it will be easy for others to help you.

Comment: Hello Sir thank you very much .. I do not know How can I add code here .. Problems a code copy in stackoverflow .. my code run very well text on image I do not know how can edit a share or download buttion below to jpg file .. just like a force download .php for other client download image over a tex

Comment: What have you tried so far?